# Diagnosing "not enough bytes" when parsing JSON with Yesod

Tags: json, http, haskell, post, yesod

I'm trying to parse the response body of a Json POST request, using the following Yesod code.

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as J
postMypageR = do
  json <- parseJsonBody :: Handler (J.Result J.Value)
  case json of
       J.Error e -> error(show e) 
       J.Success code -> do
         liftIO $ putStrLn $ show code
         defaultLayout $ myWidget
```

In my Javascript, I send with `xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({a:3, b:4}));`

The Firefox web console confirms that the string sent to POST is `{"a":3,"b":4}`.

However, when I run the code, I get the following error: `ParseError {errorContexts = [\"demandInput\"], errorMessage = \"not enough bytes\", errorPosition = 1:1}"`

Does anybody know why this might be happening? My GETs and POSTs all work in other pages, but this is the only place in my app so far where I actually look at the POST body.

Comment: Looks like the `errorPosition = 1:1` says that it received no input at all. Try Yesod's issue tracker.

Comment: Okay. Do you know how to log/print the input Yesod recieves?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this is a javascript error....  Did you set the content length before the send?

```
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
```

where `data=JSON.stringify({a:3, b:4})`

Comment: Ahh, this is probably it. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to JS. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out. I had my Send button posting from Javascript, and as a form submit, so it was sending the data, and then re-sending a POST with an empty string... whoops.